# How to replace Zentyal CA certificates and key with an already existing CA

Tags: ssl, certificate-authority, zentyal

The context: we're using a CA which is deployed on all our client machines, and a lot of hosts and web servers.

It seems that Zentyal CA module only allows to issue a new CA using the GUI, but not to import an existing CA. We'd like to use Zentyal to issue new certificates and use them in Zentyal services (admin, web server, VPN).

Is there a way to replace the CA generated through Zentyal's GUI with one created with OpenSSL CLI ?